# A Unique Problem! - D6 Motherboard Error only when Monitor is connected by Display Port

Tags: dual-boot, grub2, asus, motherboard

**System Specs:**

- Motherboard: ASUS Rampage V Edition 10
- GPU: Nvidia Geforce GTX 1080 TI
- Monitor(Problem) - Asus VG1A 144 Hz 28"
- **OS Environment - Dual Boot** [Windows 10 & Ubuntu 22.04 (or latest)]

**THE PROBLEM:**

Everything was fine until I connected this new monitor to my GPU with the same display port the old monitor was using.

Now each time I boot the PC, I get a D6 motherboard error - Which stands for "No Console Output devices Found".

Here's what happens:

1. D6 error
2. Grub boot loader doesn't load at all
3. Load straight into Ubuntu w/0 option of choosing windows

**Curious Info:**

If I remove the DisplayPort(DP), it loads normally. Then I can plug in the DP/monitor and it works fine.

I recently got a HDMI to DP port adapter... I tried that and it starts up without the D6 error.  (However, then I can't increase the monitor's refresh rate to 144Hz... it's stuck at 59.9Hz with no other options available)

To reiterate, the error didn't occur with the old monitor.

**Potential key point**

My buddy took a look and thinks I may have 'cruft", or an old version of Grub/ubuntu still installed.

I had a bad installation before, I used Windows partition maker to get rid/redo the partition.. and apparently, that's bad.

Here's what the UEFI/BIOS boot loader shows:

[image: BIOS Picture]

I tried running that **grub-fix** program...

Here's the summary it gave after doing the "recommended repair". (This didn't fix the problem)

https://paste.ubuntu.com/p/KkYTFcVYKm/

Appreciate any help.

***I'd like to go deep and learn what's going on here... Tryin to get a job in IT haha!***

Comment: this is a hardware problem :) here is a long list op things to check: https://forums.tomshardware.com/threads/no-console-output-devices-are-found.564545/